# Restrict Routes in Javascript based on firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, routes, firebase-authentication

I am building a javascript Application. This application is using a plugin called `jq-router`. When I do something like the following, the address bar changes but the view fails to change.

```
$.router.onRouteBeforeChange(function(e, route, params){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if(!user && route.protected) {
            $.router.go('landing', {}); <!-- This line calls the plugin.
        }
    });
});
```

The function in the plugin that is called above looks like the following.

```
/**
 * Navigates to given route name & params
 * @params {string} routeName
 * @params {object} params
 * @return {object} this
 */
s.go = function(routeName, params) {
    var s = this;
    paramSrv.setParams(params);
    window.location = s.href(routeName, params);
    return s;
};
```

You can access the entire plugin here: https://github.com/muzammilkm/jq-router

Again, expected result is that the view and the address bar update. Currently the only thing updating is the address bar, the view still renders.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using onViewChange/onRouteChanged events & also exclude the landing route avoid circular loop. onRouteBeforeChange event is intended to notify the route is about to change, so that if any clean up operation can be done.

```
$.router.onViewChange(function(e, viewRoute, route, params){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if(!user && route.name !== "landing" && route.protected) {
            $.router.go('landing', {}); <!-- This line calls the plugin.
        }
    });
});
```